# Find out if an iOS device is moving in a car

Tags: ios, swift

I try to find a method that helps me to find out wether a phone is moving with a car.

It doesn't matter if the phone is moved inside the car (for example if the driver picks it up to lock on it).

However I want to find out whenever the car itself moves.

I have read several articles however I can't find a way to exclude the movement inside of the car.

Comment: If the car is moving at more than 25 Kmh, which you can determine with Core Location, you can assume that the car ride has begun.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track the car movement ONLY then I would buy a wifi ODB (e.g. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Wireless-Diagnostic-Scanner-Adapter-iPhone5/dp/B00BHUNL80). Plug that into the car's ODB socket and then read the data from it with your app. You should be able to get the speed. That way you are relying on the car's movement only rather than the movement of the phone.

Here is a link to the principals needed to read data from such a device: https://blog.binaryfactory.ca/2012/07/using-an-iphone-or-ipod-touch-with-an-elm327-wifi-obd-ii/